# Lemma 2 in Knuth's "Notes on Open Addressing"

Tags: hashing

I'm trying to read Knuth's [*Notes on Open Addressing*](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/datastructures/notes/knuth-OALP.pdf), and I don't quite follow the proof of Lemma 2.

**The set-up**
We're thinking about hashing $k - 1$ keys into a size $N$ array, with collision resolution via linear probing. In particular, we're considering sequences of hash values $a_1, ..., a_{k-1}$ ($1 \leq a_i \leq N$). All we keep track of is variables $X_1, ..., X_N$, where $X_i = 0$ if the $i$th entry of the array is open, and $X_i = 1$ if the $i$th entry of the array is storing a key.

**Example**
Suppose that $N = 5$, $a_1, a_2, a_3 = 1, 4, 1$. Then $X_1 = 1$, $X_2 = 1$, $X_3 = 0$, $X_4 = 1$, $X_5 = 0$.

**Definition**
$\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}$ is the number of sequences $a_1, ..., a_k$ ($1 \leq a_i \leq n$) such that no *overflow step* occurs. The overflow step is when a key hashes to an index near the end of the array, but because $X_{\text{hash}} = X_{\text{hash} + 1} =  ... = X_N = 1$ already, we have to try to insert the key at the beginning of the array $X_1$.

In Lemma 1 Knuth proves that, for $0 \leq k \leq n + 1$, $\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix} = (n + 1)^k - k (n + 1)^{k - 1}$.

**Definition** 
$Q(N, k, t)$ is the number of sequences $a_1, .., a_{k - 1}$ ($1 \leq a_i \leq N$ satisfying (*): $X_{N - t - 1} = 0$, $X_{N - t} = ... = X_{N - 1} = 1$, $X_N = 0$.

**Proof of lemma 2**
Lemma 2 states that
$$Q(N, k, t) = \begin{bmatrix} N - t - 2 \\ k - t - 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} k - 1 \\ t \end{pmatrix}.$$

If $a_1, ..., a_{k-1}$ satisfies (*), then there is a subsequence, of length $t$, which falls into the range $X_{N - t}, ..., X_{N - 1}$. The complementary subsequence, of length $k - 1 - t$, falls into the range $X_1, ..., X_{N - t - 2}$. Knuth counts the number of each such subsequence, and the number of combining these two subsequences together to produce $a_1, ... a_{k - 1}$.

**My question**
He seems to argue that

$$Q(N, k, t) =  
\begin{bmatrix} t \\ t \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} N - t - 2 \\ k - t - 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} k - 1 \\ t \end{pmatrix}.$$

But $\begin{bmatrix} t \\ t \end{bmatrix} = (t + 1)^t - t(t+1)^{t-1} = (t + 1)^{t - 1} \not = 1$, so I don't see how the conclusion holds.

Comment: He says that by convention $\begin{bmatrix} n \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}=1$. Did he forget also to say "by convention $\begin{bmatrix} n \\ n \end{bmatrix}=1$" ?

Comment: @Maczinga I've now included the definition of $\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}$. It's not consistent with this definition to define $\begin{bmatrix} n \\ n \end{bmatrix} = 1$ "by convention".

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for your feedback, I have edited the question so that, hopefully, it is now more self contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the notes have been reported incorrectly. Indeed CruiskeenLawn, you are right. I've found some very old notes 
[here](http://algo.inria.fr/AofA/Research/11-97.html) which report the correct result. Indeed, in your copy, they simply forgot to add $\left[\begin{matrix} t\\ t\end{matrix}\right]$ term.
The Lemma you are looking for is on Page 2.